# How can I can make animation when release of hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I made a hover animation effect in css on ".animation" class. Also i added

```
transition:0.8s
```

to make the animation moves slowly.

but the animation removed immediately when I move to another html element. The animation is making the element moving 15px to left. and I want the element to go back to the original location in animation.

How can I do that?

html code:

```
<p class="animation">Hello world!</p>
```

css code:

```
p.animation:hover{padding-left:15px;transition:0.8s;}
```

please see the LIVE code here in w3schools [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNGFAU7G0G4O)

any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```css
p.animation:hover{
padding-left:15px;
transition:0.8s;
}

p.animation{
transition:0.8s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p class="animation">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `transition:0.8s` to both `p .animation` *and* `p .animation:hover`, as when you move your cursor out of the `p` element, it returns to it's original state (`p .animation`).

Comment: this answer didn't help.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer didn't help but you make me think with a different way and I tried something in same concept that you mentioned above and it worked.

The answer is:

I have to make 0px padding with same transition to the same selector without hover.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, and I'll keep that in mind for when I do my own programming!

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me i just added this code to css:

```
p.animation{
    padding-right:0px;
    transition:0.8s;
}
```